# Sonarqube 5.3, edit project level view

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube5.3

Currently Sonarqube 5.3 has a pre-configured view for project level analysis.

It basically displays the following tabs, Home button, Technical Debt, Coverage, Duplications ...Dashboard etc

[image: Tabs in SQ 5.3]

So basically I wanted to customize the sequence/remove some of the tabs etc. **Is there a way to edit the same?**

I basically want to display the custom dashboard first then some of the tabs.

I couldnt find a way to customize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to edit this fixed portion of the interface.

Comment: I think there should be an option in future releases. Although I love Sonarqube, But i need to have the flexibility configure the views the way I want. Atleast to have the flexibility to display the custom dashboard first.